# Should an answer based on a comment by a different user be considered for the accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question ["Recommendations on how to introduce an inexperienced player to the FATE combat system"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9632/recommendations-on-how-to-introduce-an-inexperienced-player-to-the-fate-combat-sy).  [mxyzplk♦](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/140/mxyzplk) responded with a comment that led me to an answer, but wasn't an answer in and of itself.  I responded with my actual answer with what worked for me.  **My question is, should my answer be considered for the accepted answer to the question?**

Comment: Actually, now that I know you liked it, I went and added it as an answer and expanded on it a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the original commenter does not post the same answer, or gives their blessing, then yes. Else give the check to the original commenter.

Comment: Agreed.  In this case I'm fine with it - I never came back to the question and I'm not hurtinl for rep :-).  In the future you may want to "call out" to the commenter by using the @mxyzplk syntax, it gives them an alert that they've been referred to.  You commented after me and called me by name, but I didn't get notifications without the @.

Comment: Ah... I didn't know the @ syntax notified you.  I'll remember that, and that's actually a good comment for this, as some others might not be aware of that detail.